Prove that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{(n+1)!}$ converges to 1
Proving the convergence can be easily done using the quotient rule.
But I'd like to prove that this series actually converges to 1.

I was thinking of proving that:

$\sum_{n=1}^m \frac{1}{2^n} \leq \sum_{n = 1}^m \frac{n}{(n+1)!}$
$\sum_{n = 1}^m \frac{n}{(n+1)!} \leq 1$

and then applying the squeeze theorem.
I tried to prove those statements by induction, but I got stuck.

Are there simpler ways to tackle this problem?

Hint: turn your sum into a telescoping one using the identity $n = (n+1) - 1$.

@achillehui Thanks, thats so much easier!

From How to ask a good question: Your question should be clear without the title. After the title has drawn someone's attention to the question by giving a good description, its purpose is done. The title is not the first sentence of your question, so make sure that the question body does not rely on specific information in the title.
